# How to edit line in file using bash

Tags: apache, bash, sed, scripting, hosting

I am trying to edit a file without making a new one, I need to change a number in a line.

This is what I have so far:

```
less php.ini | grep "upload_max_filesize"| xargs sed sed -e "s/upload_max_filesize=10M/150M/ > php.ini
```

but it just sends me to >

The line in the file currently looks like:

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 10M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've complicated things beyond need:

```
sed -i '/upload_max_filesize/s/= *10M/=150M/' php.ini
```

should suffice.

(Passing `grep` output from a pager, i.e. `less`, input to `xargs` doesn't make any sense.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, but when I input that it does not change the file and it still says upload_max_filesize = 10M

Comment: @user3186363 This should work.  Update your question to include a couple of relevant lines from your input file.

Comment: @user3186363 Your input contained spaces around `=`.  The edit above should work for you.